# How to display a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've got the following code and I'm not sure how to add the QGraphicsScene to my layout..

```
class MainForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.view.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        zoomSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        zoomSlider.setRange(5, 200)
        zoomSlider.setValue(100)
        self.pauseButton = QPushButton("Pause")
        quitButton = QPushButton("Quit")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(zoomSlider)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.startTimer(10)
```

How can I get my QGraphicsScene running?  I'm new to Qt.  Am I even supposed to be adding a QGraphicsScene to a layout/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do something like this:

```
...
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(zoomSlider)
layout.addWidget(view)
self.setLayout(layout)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added a scene to view, and it's enough. But you should add the view to your MainForm and Layout. View is a kind of widget that can be displayed by your application, while scene is not a widget and cannot be added to layout, it's a component of view. In addition, you may need to add some graphics items(e.g. rectangle, image) to scene and see how it works.